# Magento 1.9.1 - order details are not displayed in admin dashboard

Tags: magento-1.9

Order details are not displayed in admin dashboard in Magento ver. 1.9.1.1

Please find the below image

[image]

**app/code/community/AAIT/Payex2/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

2.0.23

```
<global>
    <!-- declare model group for new module -->
    <models>
        <!-- model group alias to be used in Mage::getModel('newmodule/...') -->
        <payex2>
            <!-- base class name for the model group -->
            <class>AAIT_Payex2_Model</class>
        </payex2>
    </models>

    <!-- IMPORTANT: if you use your own namespace (i.e. CompanyName) you also have to declare blocks group for new module. See topic: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/22416/#t102732 -->
    <blocks>
        <payex2>
            <class>AAIT_Payex2_Block</class>
        </payex2>
    </blocks>

    <helpers>
        <payex2>
            <class>AAIT_Payex2_Helper</class>
        </payex2>
    </helpers>

    <!-- declare resource setup for new module -->
    <resources>
        <!-- resource identifier -->
        <payex2_setup>
            <!-- specify that this resource is a setup resource and used for upgrades -->
            <setup>
                <!-- which module to look for install/upgrade files in -->
                <module>AAIT_Payex2</module>
            </setup>
            <!-- specify database connection for this resource -->
            <connection>
                <!-- do not create new connection, use predefined core setup connection -->
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </payex2_setup>
        <payex2_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </payex2_write>
        <payex2_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </payex2_read>
    </resources>

    <events>
        <sales_order_invoice_save_after>
            <observers>
                <payex2>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>payex2/observer</class>
                    <method>sales_order_invoice_save_after</method>
                </payex2>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_invoice_save_after>
    </events>
</global>

<!-- declare default configuration values for this module -->
<default>
    <!-- 'payment' configuration section (tab) -->
    <payment>
        <!-- 'newmodule' configuration group (fieldset) -->
        <payex2>
            <!-- by default this payment method is inactive -->
            <active>1</active>
            <!-- model to handle logic for this payment method -->
            <model>payex2/payment</model>
            <!-- default title for payment checkout page and order view page -->
            <title>Payex Payments</title>
            <paymentview>PX</paymentview>
            <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
            <debug>1</debug>
            <accountnumber>payex account number</accountnumber>
            <encryptionkey>payex encryption key</encryptionkey>
            <transactiontype>1</transactiontype>
            <order_status_authorize>processing</order_status_authorize>
            <order_status_capture>complete</order_status_capture>
            <clientlanguage>en-US</clientlanguage>
            <cleantime>20</cleantime>
            <responsive>0</responsive>
        </payex2>
    </payment>
</default>

<adminhtml>
    <!-- Updates layout... -->
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <payex2>
                <file>payex2_admin.xml</file>
            </payex2>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>

<frontend>
    <!-- Routes... -->
    <routers>
        <payex2>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>AAIT_Payex2</module>
                <frontName>payex2</frontName>
            </args>
        </payex2>
    </routers>

    <!-- Translations... -->
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <AAIT_Payex2>
                <files>
                    <default>AAIT_Payex2.csv</default>
                </files>
            </AAIT_Payex2>
        </modules>
    </translate>
</frontend>

<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <payex2_clean_pending_orders>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>payex2/observer::cleanPendingOrders</model>
            </run>
        </payex2_clean_pending_orders>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

How to rectify this issue.

Comment: have you checked the error log?

Comment: i have tried but it's not working.

Comment: var/log/ check this folder

Comment: I have deleted log files also but it's not working.

Comment: check the error in log file i am not asking to delete the file

Comment: in system.log file  
2015-05-25T11:46:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Payex/Model/Standard.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/halsorutan/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2015-05-25T11:46:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Payex/Model/Standard.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/halsorutan/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

Comment: In error log file 
[25-May-2015 11:58:00 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mage_Payex_Helper_Data' not found in /home/halsorutan/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547

Comment: have you installed this extension?

Comment: Yes i have installed this extension

Comment: check the answer

Comment: @SivaKumar So, How did you solved it - Which module/extension did you disabled or what code/db changes have you done? - Facing same

Answer (score 1):

I have seen that the same issue had been answered before, below i am pasting the link in order to check it out.

[Order Details are not displayed in dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556164/magento-order-details-are-not-displayed-in-the-admin-panel)

Comment: I have tried but it's not working.

Comment: i saw that at the link i gave a guy says he solved by replacing the tax.phtml file which is located in 'app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/totals'  with the original one. Have you tried this ?

Comment: That one also i have tried it's not working

Comment: i don't know what is going on. Just continue the research, if i find something i will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

go to app/etc/modules/spanename_Payex.xml

open it and change **true** to **false**
problem with this extension it has some file missing with is causing the problems.

Comment: When i change to true it is showing below error

{main}";s:3:"url";s:86:"/index.php/admin/sales_order/view/order_id/16320/key/a04a09d9abac2f404201797b0166e7e9/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}

Comment: set it   to false the the module will be disabled or delete it if you install from magento connect

Comment: Sorry I have changed to false only.

Comment: now order view working?

Comment: Not working it is showing below error. 
{main}";s:3:"url";s:86:"/index.php/admin/sales_order/view/order_id/16320/key/a04‌​a09d9abac2f404201797b0166e7e9/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s‌​:5:"admin";}

Comment: When i refresh the re index management it is showing error .
There was a problem with reindexing process. 

'Product Prices' Index Process InformationBackReindex DataSave Process

Comment: AAIT_Payex2.xml 

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <AAIT_Payex2>
            <active>false</active>
<!-- this module will be located in app/code/local code pool -->
            <codePool>community</codePool>
<!-- specify dependencies for correct module loading order -->
            <depends>
                <Mage_Payment />
            </depends>
<!-- declare module's version information for database updates -->
            <version>2.0.23</version>
        </AAIT_Payex2>
    </modules>
</config>

Comment: show me the code  app/code/local/AAIT_Payex2/etc/config.xml

Comment: Config.xml  so big code.

Comment: post in ur question

Comment: now u can check the question.

Comment: code app/code/local/AAIT/Payex2 rename this folder  disable from AAIT_Payex2.xml

Answer (score 1):

Try also this, it worked for me (from https://magentary.com/kb/php-syntax-error-after-supee-7405-unexpected/):

> **Problem description**
>
> After SUPEE-7405 patch Sales Order Management screen in Magento Backend is blank or the following error is reported in PHP error log:
>
> > PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php on line 124
>
> **Cause**
>
> SUPEE-7405 is prepared with PHP 5.4 in mind, older PHP versions are incompatible with new language constructions used.
>
> **Solution**
>
> Change line 124 in *app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php* from `$links = [];` to `$links = array();`:
>
> ```
> --- app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
> +++ app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
>
> @@ -121,7 +121,7 @@
>      public function escapeHtmlWithLinks($data, $allowedTags = null)
>      {
>          if (!empty($data) && is_array($allowedTags) && in_array('a', $allowedTags)) {
> -            $links = [];
> +            $links = array();
>              $i = 1;
>              $data = str_replace('%', '%%', $data);
> ```

Comment: This site helped me many times...  Now I found a solution for a problem that I am struggling for a few days now and I had to share it with you! Good luck guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it can also be the short_open_tag in the php.ini. set it to

```
short_open_tag = On
```